# What is "seal saver"?

Tags: crankshaft, seal, oil-seal

I recently replaced the oil pump in my dad's 1990 Mazda b2200 only to find that after I replaced it it started leaking from the crankshaft seal. He took it in to a local mechanic who pulled everything back apart and my dad says he used something called a "seal saver" to fix the leak. Has anybody heard of this product before? If so, do you know where I could buy it and how it is used?

I've tried to research it and I'm wondering what he bought is something that I've seen elsewhere referred to as a crankshaft repair sleeve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see two possibilities:

1. He just putted some leak-stop additive in the engine oil. That is some additive that is intended to stop an seal leak by miraculously thickening the oil around the seal area and not in the oil channels (where it needs to flow unobstructed). Needless to say that this additives most of the time do an awful job.
2. The crankshaft seal got replaced. Perhaps the crankshaft seal, in combination with dirt or grime, over time scratched an groove in the crankshaft and the mechanic repaired the shaft by applying a repair sleeve (google SKF speedi sleeve) over the crankshaft so that the new seal can do its job.

The sleeve is just a ferrule made of very thin metal that get pushed over the damaged part of the shaft. Since this forms a very smooth surface the new seal can do its job without getting damaged by a rough surface

Comment: I know for sure it wasn't #1. The oil pump that I replaced came with a new seal, which I did install along with the pump, but it didn't do its job. He must have used a sleeve to get the seal to hold.  The reference to speedi sleeve is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!